# How to get URL of shop in Shopify embeded app?

Tags: node.js, firefox, iframe, shopify, shopify-app

I'm building a Shopify App using this template: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node/tree/cli_three and I was wondering how I'm able to get the URL of the shop that is using my app (means the URL of the document outside the iFrame). I had a working approach using `location.ancestorOrigins` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/ancestorOrigins), but since this is not compatible with Firefox, I was wondering if there is another approach. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to create an API endpoint to fetch the shop details, query it in the front-end and utilise it.
My example uses `node.js` and `React` in front-end.

`backend/index.js`

```js
app.get("/api/shop", async (_req, res) => {
// Refer to docs: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/shop#resource-object
  const shopData = await shopify.api.rest.Shop.all({
    session: res.locals.shopify.session,
  });
  res.status(200).send(shopData);
});
```

`frontend/index.js`

```js
// Utilize app query hook provided by node.js/react template from shopify
import { useAppQuery } from "../hooks";

export default function HomePage() {
  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
  } = useAppQuery({
    url: "/api/shop"
  });
 // Do something while data is loading
...
 // Else return page
 console.log("DATA", data);
 return (
    <Page>
      <Text variant="headingLg" as="h3">
         Welcome to {data.data[0].name} App
       </Text>
    </Page>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! In fact, this is how you should do this with the current version. I mark this as the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I came up with a solution by myself, but thanks for your help @TwistedOwl and @David Lazar. I post my code here in case anyone has the same problem in the future:

```js
import {useAppBridge} from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";

function DemoPage() {
    const bridge = useAppBridge();
    const shopUrl = bridge.hostOrigin.replace('https://', '').replace('www.', '');
    console.log(shopUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All calls to your App provide a shop parameter (and now a host parameter too) ensuring you always know the shopify store using your App. There are zero situations where your App is called without the shop parameter being part of the equation from Shopify.

Comment: I think @M.Singer is asking how to get the shop URL on the frontend part, not the backend, but I am not sure.

Comment: @TwistedOwl yes that's right. I want to use it in a page within the frontend part of the app

Comment: Ok. well, I will double down. If you are in fact legit working on a Shopify App, then you have to understand that the shop you are working with is known 100% of the time. For the back-end calls it is the shop param, and for any front-end code there is the old Liquid shop object. You cannot possibly run any code in an App or via an App and not understand this. If you need to rely on the browser for info from the URL, are you doing something pretty out there? Just my opinion, but hey, you get it for free!